# Strange behavior when defining a value for True in Python

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-expression

This isn't a practical problem - I'm just curious about some strange behavior I've observed, and wondering if I understand the "is" operator correctly.

Here's some predictable Python interpreter output:

```
>>> True is True
True
>>> (1==1) is True
True
```

Now let's define a variable called True:

```
>>> True = 'abc'
>>> True == 'abc'
True
>>> True is 'abc'
True
```

The interpreter will still return "True" for boolean operations, but the results of boolean operations are considered equivalent to neither 'abc' nor True.

```
>>> (1==1)
True
>>> (1==1) is 'abc'
False
>>> (1==1) is True
False
```

Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

Comment: Odd that `True` isn't a reserved keyword (or whatever Python has).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: `True` has become a keyword in Python 3, and the assignment would have raised `SyntaxError: assignment to keyword`.

Comment: most built-ins aren't keywords... you can reassign values to almost all of them. thankfully they are usually local, so when an unwary programmer does it in their function, it stays localized there.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: for example `id` is a built in function, yet it's very often reassigned as object property (eg. in Django ORM). I'm not sure if it's "unwary", given that `id()` builtin isn't much useful for anything other than debugging.

Comment: as an object property, it's OK - this isn't C, you will always access it as `self.id` or `object.id` (in a namespace). though I have seen (and even written) code like `for id in list_of_uids:` etc., so it's a very good point that it's easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a bit more to your own answer (should be a comment, but, long and needs formatting):

```
python2.7
...
>>> import __builtin__
>>> id(True)
7744528
>>> id(__builtin__.True)
7744528
>>> True = 'abc'
>>> id(True)
34386540544
```

The value from `id` is (essentially) the internal identity, or "true name" if you like, of an object in Python.  (It's literally a C pointer turned into an integer.)  The `is` test compares object-identity.

```
>>> 1==1
True
>>> id(1==1)
7744528
```

This shows that the boolean-result of a comparison is the "old" `True`, the one still available as `__builtin__.True`.

You re-bound the name `__main__.True` (your current module at the interpreter `>>>` prompt is `__main__`):

```
>>> True
'abc'
>>> __builtin__.True
True
```

and:

```
>>> import __main__
>>> id(__main__.True)
34386540544
>>> __main__.True
'abc'
>>>
```

This same thing happens quite often in beginners' Python programs when they write functions like:

```
def foo(list):
    ...
```

`list` is a built-in function, but inside function `foo`, the name has been re-bound to the argument.  Then somewhere in the `...` part they get a surprise:

```
    x = list(y)
```

They expect this to invoke `__builtin__.list`, but it tries to call their local variable as a function instead.

(It's possible, but not generally good style, to `import __builtin__` and call things through those names instead.  It's also possible to re-bind the `__builtin__` names, but that's an even worse idea. :-) )

Answer (score 6):

As often happens on here, I think I figured out the answer while I was typing up the question.

There are two "True"s: one is a boolean value, and the other is the variable called True; initially, they're equal to each other. This is why boolean operations like (1==1) can still return True even when the variable called True has been changed - they're returning the boolean value True. Yet they're not equal to the new value of the "True" variable, which is a string.

Comment: I love it when that happens!

Comment: @JMK Yea, I was like, Imma be the first to answer this :P I didn't see his answer.

Comment: `True` is basically `1` with a fancy `repr()`.  :-)

Comment: True is not `1` with a fancy `repr()`.  It's a singleton, builtin value that happens to evaluate to 1 in a condition.  As far as the interpreter is concerned, there's nothing wrong with using a different singleton value that also has this behavior such as `if Ellipsis: print 3`, apart from the obvious obscurity that makes this stylistically egregious.

As you can tell from the `Ellipsis` example (where ellipsis also has a different slicing function in numpy arrays that nobody uses), the value of a singleton can't be thought of as like `1`.  For instance, compare `True+1` and `Ellipsis+1`

Comment: `isinstance(True, int)`

Answer (score 5):

That's happening is namespaceing and interactive console hiding it.

Initially you have normal `True`, which is part of `__builtin__` module.

When you redefine `True`, you're actually defining it in a current module, which in that case is just default one `__main__`.

Thus you actually have two different objects. `__builtin__.True` and `__main__.True`.

```
In [1]: import __builtin__, __main__

In [2]: True = "a bad idea"

In [3]: __main__.True
Out[3]: 'a bad idea'

In [4]: __builtin__.True
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: that explains how you can hide it... but you can also do `__builtin__.True = 4` if you want. so this doesn't completely answer the original question.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: I'm explaining what is happening in the code in the original question.

Comment: i'm just saying that it's deeper than that... you can do `__builtin__.True = 4`, and `1==1` will still return True. something even below the __builtin__ points to the real object, or it's handled in the python core.